# Use PreparedStatement with Sqlbrite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlbrite

I'm migrating all my sql related codes to use Sqlbrite. Currently I have code that look something like this:

```
Cursor cursor;
String name;
String[] selectionArgs = { name };
cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_USER, new String[] {"id"}, "name = ? COLLATE NOCASE AND ", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Now I need to use SqlBrite, but I want to use Prepared Statement with it. Is there any way I can do this? I googled 'SqlBrite PreparedStatement' but couldn't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use `executeInsert` and `executeUpdateDelete` on your instance of `BriteDatabase`. They accept a `SQLiteStatement` as a parameter.